# Error at line 474455: Unknown command '\a'

Tags: mysql, database, restore

Im traing to import a bk to mysql via the command line but i get this error:

ERROR at line 474455: Unknown command '\a'

but i cant find that text.

This is the line:

```
INSERT INTO `pedwebart` (`csid`, `secuencia`, `codart`, `codivaart`, `codclabon`, `desartamp`, `fecentart`, `canart`, `preart`, `impbonart`, `impgraart`, `impdesart`, `imprecart`, `impnetgraart`, `impivaart`) VALUES
```

Comment: you VERY obviously don't have `474455` lines in your code sample above, and nowhere does `\a` show up in what you did post, so we can't help you.

Comment: That line is the error line. the sql file have 475023 lines so i dont upload the complete file. If it is necessary i can do it.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm facing this exact error.
EDIT: Ok it turns out that I exported the database with phpmyadmin. I opened the .sql file and at the end, phpmyadmin printed an HTML error saying "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 360 seconds exceeded". Instead of displaying an error during the export process, phpMyAdmin write the error in the sql file… Non sense.

Answer (score 2):

this solution worked for me.

**Problem Statement:** Error at line 474455: Unknown command '\a'

**Solution:** This is nothing related to '\a' actually. Your database file probably has an HTML error written at the end of your .sql file as follows:

```
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-fatal-error' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 360 seconds exceeded in D:\wamp64\apps\phpmyadmin4.9.2\libraries\classes\Export.php on line <i>90</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0018</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>625848</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='D:\wamp64\apps\phpmyadmin4.9.2\export.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\export.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0697</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>1324496</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>PhpMyAdmin\Export::exportDatabase(  )</td><td title='D:\wamp64\apps\phpmyadmin4.9.2\export.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\export.php<b>:</b>470</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>3</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>304.8660</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>2148024</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\Export\ExportSql->exportData(  )</td><td title='D:\wamp64\apps\phpmyadmin4.9.2\libraries\classes\Export.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\Export.php<b>:</b>701</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>4</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>360.0001</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>2180424</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>PhpMyAdmin\Export::outputHandler(  )</td><td title='D:\wamp64\apps\phpmyadmin4.9.2\libraries\classes\Plugins\Export\ExportSql.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\ExportSql.php<b>:</b>2499</td></tr>
</table></font>
```

This Error is printed by PHPMyAdmin at the time when the user exports the database. The user must increase the **max_execution_time** in order to export the database successfully without any error.
Once successfully created, you will not see the '\a' error again. :)

> The problem is with exporting the database from PHPMyAdmin, not Importing with PHPMyAdmin/Terminal.

I hope this solution solves your problem.